# Is there a specific word that means, "a quote from a poem?"

Tags: word-choice, quotes, poetry

I was wondering if there is a simpler way to say, "a quote from a poem." I thought about the word excerpt, but that seems to apply to a bigger chunk of writing. Whereas in this instance, I am referring to five short lines of text in a poem.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A ***[quotation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quotation):***

> - ***a phrase or passage from a book, poem, play, etc,*** remembered and spoken, esp to illustrate succinctly or support a point or an argument.

(Collins)

A [quote](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quote) can also be used as a synonym of quotation, but it is less common.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20quotation%20from%20a%20poem%2Ca%20quote%20from%20a%20poem&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20quotation%20from%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20quote%20from%20a%20poem%3B%2Cc0): *a quotation from a poem* vs a *quote from a poem*

Usage Note:

> - ***People have been using the noun quote as a truncation of quotation for over one hundred years, and its use in less formal contexts is widespread today.*** Language critics have objected to this usage, however, as unduly journalistic or breezy, but the word appears to have gained acceptance.

(AHD)

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if "quotation" was directed more towards short phrases in texts such as books and articles over poetry. Your response was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For a poem or a novel, you may replace "quotation" (*that perfectly fits*) by **excerpt**.

> Definition:  a passage or quotation taken or selected from a book, document, film, or the like
>
> Example: I've read only excerpts of Moby-Dick, never the whole book.